# Jersey Utilizing Wrong Message Body Writer Provider

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have recently started using jersey 1.6 to develop Rest web services.  I have 2 services that are producing JSON.  I have setup MessageBodyWriters for both of them to handle the Object to Json conversion.  I finished my first web service and everything is working great and as expected.  When trying to implement my 2nd service, I am running into an issue of Jersey calling the messagebodywriter provider that I setup for the 1st web service instead of the new one I created.  This is generating a class cast exception.  If I remove the provider from the 1st service so that only the 2nd one is there, it works as expected.  Below is what I have setup:

**Service #1**

```
  @POST
    @Path("/medical")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public RateListWrapper getMedicalRate(@FormParam("zip") String zip, @FormParam("cpt")     List<String> cptList, @FormParam("dos") String dos, @FormParam("mod1") List<String> mod1List, 
            @FormParam("mod2") List<String> mod2List, @FormParam("mod3") List<String> mod3List, @FormParam("mod4") List<String> mod4List, @FormParam("units") List<String> unitsList,
            @FormParam("pos") List<String> posList) {
    }
```

**Service #1 Provider**

```
@Provider
public class RateListWraperProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<RateListWrapper>{

    @Override
    public long getSize(RateListWrapper t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        //System.out.println("Get Size");
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        //System.out.println("Is Writable");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(RateListWrapper t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.serializeNulls().create();
        entityStream.write(gson.toJson(t).getBytes());

    }

}
```

**Service #2**

```
@POST
@Path("/medical/post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public RbrvsListWrapper medicalRatePost(@FormParam("zip") String zip, @FormParam("facilitytype") String facilityType, @FormParam("cpt") List<String> cptList, @FormParam("dos") String dos, @FormParam("mod1") List<String> mod1List) {
    return getMedicalRate(zip, facilityType, cptList, dos, mod1List);
}
```

**Service #2 Provider**

```
@Provider
public class RbrvsListWrapperProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<RbrvsListWrapper>{

    @Override
    public long getSize(RbrvsListWrapper t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        //System.out.println("Get Size");
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        //System.out.println("Is Writable");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(RbrvsListWrapper t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.serializeNulls().create();
        entityStream.write(gson.toJson(t).getBytes());

    }



}
```

**Here is my Jersey configuration in my web.xml:**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.dataws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Update**

I upgraded to 1.17 and the problem persists.  Here is the stack trace that is happening for the class cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dataws.json.RbrvsListWrapper cannot be cast to com.dataws.json.RateListWrapper
    at com.dataws.provider.RateListWraperProvider.getSize(RateListWraperProvider.java:1)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:289)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Hi Paul, please update to Jersey 1.17 or (preferably!) to 2.4.1. Version 1.6 is really old and it might be hard to provide relevant support.

Comment: ok thanks, I will update to 1.7 for now and check back with the results!

Comment: @PavelBucek I updated to 1.7 and the problem persists.  I updated my post with the stack trace I am getting.

Comment: Try `1.17`, not `1.7`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I thought it was 1.7.  I double checked and I do have 1.17 there with the same issue

Comment: @PaulZepernick you can just use Jackson instead of GSON which will be easier. If you are using Jackson, there's no need to write a message writer.

Comment: @mallim I had issues with an older version of Jersey telling me there was no provider when I tried to use Jackson before.  That is why I went down the road of creating my own providers and then just used Gson since that is what I am more familiar with.  I put Jackson back in and removed my providers.  It is now working with 1.17 !!  Wish I knew what the provider problem was for the future.  I don't know if it was my setup or a bug in Jersey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used @maslim suggestion and used Jackson to create the JSON.  Removed my custom providers and both services are working as expected now.